# UISlider value can't be accessed by function in ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I get an error saying "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION..." in reference to attempting to use redSlider.value to set a value for a property of my "Color" type from another file.(also pasted below)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var colorView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var redSlider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var greenSlider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var blueSlider: UISlider!

    func updateCurrentColor() {
        var currentColor = Color(red: redSlider.value, green: greenSlider.value, blue: blueSlider.value)
        print("CurrentColor updated!!!")
    }
}
```

And here is my "Color" Type(in another file):

```
import Foundation

struct  Color {
    var red = Float()
    var green = Float()
    var blue = Float()
}
```

[Here is my ViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkQE6.png)

I call updateCurrentColor() from main.swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

ViewController().updateCurrentColor()
```

Comment: Are all your sliders IBOutlets connected? Can you post an image of your VC in Interface builder?

Comment: From where do you call updateCurrentColor()?

Comment: Do you create a second `ViewController` somewhere and try to access its outlets without loading its views?

Comment: did you set range in your sliders  0 and 255?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ViewController()` creates a new view controller object.  Since you don't present it on the screen, its outlets never get initialized.  That means that the `!` on the end of `redSlider: UISlider!` is a lie.

Even if it didn't crash, updating the color on something you're not putting on the screen doesn't sound very useful.

Use the `ViewController` you already have instead of creating a new one.